# Groovy reports that a file doesn't exists when it really is present in the system

Tags: jenkins, file-io, groovy, jenkins-plugins

Whenever a build of my Jenkins job finishes, I'm sending an email with the results using the `Editable Email Notification` plugin (a.k.a. `Email-ext` plugin).
Also, if a certain file is present in the system, I'm modifying the default content of the message to notify of the existence of that file.

For that end, I'm using the `Pre-send Script` field of the plugin.

## Test job configuration:

### Prepare an environment for the run




#### Properties Content

```
LOG="log.txt"
```

### Build stage

### #### Execute shell

```
#!/bin/bash

touch ${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}
echo "this is just a log" >> ${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}
```

### Post-build Actions




#### Editable Email Notification


*Pre-send Script*

```
File log = new File("${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}");
logger.println(log.text);
```

---

When executing the build, `Jenkins` will create the file in the `${WORKSPACE}` and fill it (I'm able to print the contents from the terminal in the Jenkins slave).

But when trying to access it from the `Email` plugin, the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is raised:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/workspace/testJob/log.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.<init>(CharsetToolkit.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.newReader(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:16958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getText(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:16006)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$381.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.doMethodInvoke(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:70)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3500)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:59)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.executePresendScript(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:450)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:311)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:297)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:244)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:195)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1785)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

I'm at a loss as why `Groovy` is complaining about the missing file, whereas if I instead print the path with

```
logger.println(log.getPath());
```

it will print it successfully.

**NOTE:**
The `logger` variable in the `Pre-send Script` is provided by the notification plugin to access directly the build log.

Comment: Is it possible that the post-build action gets executed on the jenkins master rather than on the slave? The logger object might be shared across the nodes, which is why the `log.getPath()` returns a path, but the file itself might not be present on the master node.

Comment: @fishi Indeed, it seems that the post-build action is executed in the Slave. I printed the `hostname` of the machine instead of creating files and it reported the Master's. The question remains as how could I be able to access that file from the Master...

Comment: One option would be to copy the file to the master. If you use Jenkins pipeline scripts you could use [stash/unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build). But judging from the question it seems you are not using Jenkins pipeline. In that case you could have a look at [Copy to slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) (even though the name suggests otherwise, you can also copy from slave to master with it).

Comment: @fishi You are right. I'm not using the pipeline, but I will take a look into it, to see if it would be possible to modify the job to adopt it.
Otherwise, I will go with the `Copy to slave` plugin approach.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`java.io.File` methods will refer to files on the ***master*** where Jenkins is running, and not in the current workspace on the ***slave*** machine (in case this job indeed runs on a slave machine).

To refer to files on the slave machine, you should use the `readFile` method

```
def log = readFile("${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}");
```

Comment: A side note: this will work if the groovy code is within the Pipeline. If you want to read a file on a slave from a shared library, it's not really possible, as described here -  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56384.

Answer (score 15):

Within a Jenkins pipeline, `File log = new File("${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}");` doesn't work. 
You can use [readFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace) instead, e.g.:

```
def log = readFile "${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}"
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. As @MorLajb  suggested, it seems to be running on the master.

Comment: Yeah, what a pain in the butt. Would be so much better if Pipelines could just be pure Groovy.

Comment: Yes, this is an expected behaviour of Jenkins:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37577

Comment: And how would we create/write to the file ?? example I have a list that I want to write to file which is easily done by File.append() ??

Answer (score 0):

I had a jenkins Job with the same problem. `readFile`method didn't work for me because I used a [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) (had an error like *No signature of method readFile()*), so I used the [readFileFromWorkspace](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.readFileFromWorkspace) method and it worked for me.

Your code should be modified like:

```
def log = readFileFromWorkspace("${WORKSPACE}/${LOG}");
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'readFileFromWorkspace' found among steps