# File.exists() in a Jenkins groovy file does not work

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a groovy function in my Jenkins job that looks into a folder and deletes all files who are older than X days.

So I start looking in the internet and found different kind of solutions.

At first I create a `.groovy` file with Visual Studio Code on my local PC to understand how it works. That is the reason why my code looks not similar to the codes in the internet because I changed it so that I understand how the code works.

```
def deleteFilesOlderThanDays(int daysBack, String path) {
  def DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  File directory = new File(path)

  if(directory.exists()){
    File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles()
    
    for(File listFile : listFiles) {
      def days_from_now = ( (System.currentTimeMillis() - listFile.lastModified()) /(DAY_IN_MILLIS))
      if(days_from_now > daysBack) {
        println('------------')
        println('file is older')
        println(listFile)
        }
        else{
          println('------------')
          println('File is not older')
          println(listFile)
        }
      }//End: for(File listFile : listFiles) {
    }//End: if(directory.exists()){
}
```

(I know, the code do not delete something. It is only for my understanding)

The second step was to include this new created function into my Jenkins groovy file. But since then I'm desperate.

I have the problem that I do not get a positive result at the beginning from the code if the folder really exist.

The line:

```
if(directory.exists()){
```

makes me a lot of problems and it is not clear for me why.

I have tried so many kind of versions but I haven’t found a solution for me.
I have also used the “Pipeline Syntax” example [Sample Step fileExists] but it doesn’t help for me.

I have included:

```
import java.io.File
```

At the beginning of my file.

I have a basic file which I include in the Jenkins job. This file includes my library files. One of this library files is the `file.groovy`. In the basic Jenkins file I execute the function `file.deleteFilesOlderThanDays()` (for testing I do not use any parameters).

The code from my function for testing is:

```
def deleteFilesOlderThanDays() {

  dir = '.\\ABC'
  echo "1. ----------------------------------------"
  File directory1 = new File('.\\ABC\\')
  exist = directory1.exists()
  echo 'Directory1 name is = '+directory1
  echo 'exist value is = '+exist
  echo "2. ----------------------------------------"
  File directory2 = new File('.\\ABC')
  exist = directory2.exists()
  echo 'Directory2 name is = '+directory2
  echo 'exist value is = '+exist
  echo "3. ----------------------------------------"  
  File directory3 = new File(dir)
  exist = directory3.exists()
  echo 'Directory3 name is = '+directory3
  echo 'exist value is = '+exist
  echo "4. Pipeline Syntax ------------------------"  
  exist = fileExists '.\\ABC'
  echo 'exist value is = '+exist
  echo "5. ----------------------------------------"
  File directory5 = new File(dir)
  echo 'Directory5 name is = '+directory5
  // execute an error
  // exist = fileExists(directory5)
  exist = fileExists "directory5"
  echo 'exist value is = '+exist
  echo "6. ----------------------------------------"
  exist = fileExists(dir)
  echo 'exist value is = '+exist

  File[] listFiles = directory5.listFiles()
  echo 'List file = '+listFiles
}
```

And the Output in the Jenkins Console Output is: (I cleaned it a little bit up….)

```
1. ----------------------------------------
Directory1 name is = .\ABC\
exist value is = false
2. ----------------------------------------
Directory2 name is = .\ABC
exist value is = false
3. ----------------------------------------
Directory3 name is = .\ABC
exist value is = false
4. Pipeline Syntax ------------------------
exist value is = true
5. ----------------------------------------
Directory5 name is = .\ABC
exist value is = false
6. ----------------------------------------
exist value is = true

List file = null
```

I only get a true value in step 4 and 6. So I can be sure that the folder really exist.

So it seems to be for me that the command:

```
File directory = new File(dir)
```

Not work correct in my case.

I can’t create a `listFile` variable because the directory would not be initialized correct.

For me is also not clear which kind of commands I should use. The groovy examples use always functions like:

```
 .exists()
```

But in the Jenkins examples I always find code like this:

```
  fileExists()
```

Why there are some differences between groovy and Jenkins groovy style? It should be the same ore not?

Does anyone have an idea for me or can told me what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Jenkins Groovy != Groovy. The Jenkins Groovy language is a specialized compiler and runtime for Groovy source that does not behave exactly like normal Groovy execution. [This comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/TtaIXm8OUl0/aNfY_6SNAAAJ) can be helpful, as well as possibly my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590101/627727).

Answer (score 2):

You may benefit from this answer from a similar question:

"
`java.io.File` methods will refer to files on the master where Jenkins is running, so not in the current workspace on the slave machine.

To refer to files on the slave machine, you should use the readFile method
"

```
def dir = readFile("${WORKSPACE}/ABC");
```

[Link to original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503979/3229947)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all that feedback.

OK, for me is now clear that Jenkins Groovy != Groovy is.
I have read a lot about it that there are different command if you are executing file search on a Jenkins Master or on a Jenkins Slave.

The suggestion from Youg to start after confirmation helps me.
I had problems with deleting the file so at the end I used a primitive batch command to get my function run.

The finally functions looks like now:

```
def deleteFilesOlderThanXDays(daysBack, path) {

  def DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

  if(fileExists(path)){
    // change into path
    dir(path) {

      // find all kind of files
    files = findFiles(glob: '*.*')

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

      def days_from_now = ( (System.currentTimeMillis() - files[i].lastModified) /(DAY_IN_MILLIS))

      if(days_from_now > daysBack) {
        echo('file : >>'+files[i].name+'<< is older than '+daysBack+' days')
        bat('del /F /Q "'+files[i].name+'"')
        }
        else{
          echo('file : >>'+files[i].name+'<< is not only than '+daysBack+' days')
        }
      }// End: for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    }// End: dir(path) {
  }// End: if(fileExists(path)){
}
```

Thanks for helping and best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can add below script to list the file and folders in current work directory, so that you can confirm the folder `ABC` is exists or not.

After you confirm the `ABC` folder exist, then dig into the rest code.

```
def deleteFilesOlderThanDays() {

  // print current work directory
  pwd

  // if jenkins job run on window machine
  bat 'dir'

  // if jenkins job run on linux machine    
  sh 'ls -l'

  dir = '.\\ABC'
  echo "1. ----------------------------------------"
  .....
```

For `fileExists` usage, I think the correct way as following:

```
fileExists './ABC'

def dir = './ABC'
fileExists dir
```

Should use `/` as path separator, rather than `\` according to its document at below:
[image]