# Send email only when environment variable has specific value in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-email-ext

I have Master-Slave jenkins setup. In one of the jenkins job, I need to send an email via `Editable Email Notification` plugin only when environment variable has specific value. So I am setting the value of environment variable in `Execute Shell` command as below

`echo "SHOULD_SEND_EMAIL=$should_send_email" > $WORKSPACE/build/env.properties`

In post build action, I have a step to send email with `Script-After Build` trigger & has below trigger script

```
def workspace = build.getWorkspace()
println "Value of workspace is ${workspace}"

filename = workspace.toString() + "/build/env.properties"
println "Value of filename is ${filename}"

def logs = readFile("${filename}")
println "Value of logs is ${logs}"
```

But it fails below error

```
 15:05:54 Value of workspace is /Users/jenkins/workspace/experiment-job
15:05:54 Value of filename is /Users/jenkins/workspace/experiment-job/build/env.properties
15:05:54 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
15:05:54 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.readFile() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [/Users/jenkins/workspace/experiment-job/build/env.properties]
15:05:54    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
15:05:54    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
15:05:54    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
15:05:54    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
15:05:54    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
15:05:54    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:7)
15:05:54    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
15:05:54    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
15:05:54    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
15:05:54    at hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.AbstractScriptTrigger.trigger(AbstractScriptTrigger.java:55)
15:05:54    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:269)
15:05:54    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:253)
15:05:54    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:195)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1788)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
15:05:54    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
15:05:54 Build step 'Editable Email Notification' marked build as failure
```

I tried passing hardcoded value of file considering readFile will ready from workspace instead of absolute path as below

```
def logs = readFile("/build/env.properties")
println "Value of logs is ${logs}"
```

But it still fails below error

```
14:55:32 Value of workspace is /Users/jenkins/workspace/experiment-job
14:55:32 Value of filename is /Users/jenkins/workspace/experiment-job/build/env.properties
14:55:32 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
14:55:32 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.readFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [build/env.properties]
14:55:32    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
14:55:32    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
14:55:32    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
14:55:32    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
14:55:32    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
14:55:32    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:7)
14:55:32    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
14:55:32    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
14:55:32    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
14:55:32    at hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.AbstractScriptTrigger.trigger(AbstractScriptTrigger.java:55)
14:55:32    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:269)
14:55:32    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:253)
14:55:32    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:195)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1788)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
14:55:32    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
14:55:32 Build step 'Editable Email Notification' marked build as failure
```

I can not use File as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503979/1465536 . 
Can someone help me understand what is the issue here? If you have any other solution to send an email depending on condition, I happy to know it as well. Thank you.

Comment: What the error is saying is that the `workspace` method cannot be operated on with a `toString()` method because its return is not of an acceptable type. You will need to access your workspace path some other way (I suggest an intrinsic environment variable like `env.WORKSPACE`). Besides that, it is unclear to me what relationship your question and your example code have to each other.

Answer (score -1):

The error hints a wrong usage of `readFile`, change to following:

```
def logs = readFile file: filename
```